# Mockito's reified mock method typing the mock as the superclass instead of generic type

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit5

I want to provide a simpler interface (utility method) to mock a construction of a class we often need mocked in many tests because it's constructed by a third party library. This class is generic typed and has a method that return it's generics (`ClassIWantMockedConstructor<T> { whatever(): T }`). The utility method is something like this:

```java
public interface Execution<T extends ParentClass> {
    void execute(T mock) throws Exception;
}
    
public static <T extends ParentClass> void withMockedConstruction(Execution<T> execution) {
    T mock = mock();
    try (@SuppressWarnings("unused") MockedConstruction<?> construction = mockConstruction(
            ClassIWantMockedConstructor.class,
            (mocked, ctx) -> when(mocked.whatever()).thenReturn(mock)
    )) {
        execution.execute(mock);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected error during tests, please check the tests", t);
    }
}
```

However, if I use `withMockedConstruction` passing an lambda typed with a child class of ParentClass, then `T` is still typed as `ParentClass`. Which will cause a `ClassCastException` later down the line. Example:

```java
// When called like this
withMockedConstruction((ChildClass mockService) -> { ... });

// Then debugging
public static <T extends ParentClass> void withMockedConstruction(Execution<T> execution) {
    T mock = mock(); // mock = Mock for ParentClass, T reified as ParentClass
    ...
        execution.execute(mock); // throws ClassCastException
}
```

The only way I could overcome this was by specifying manually a class for the mock, thus changing the signature to require the class as following:

```java
// Change signature to this:
public static <T extends ParentClass> void withMockedConstruction(Class<T> clazz, Execution<T> execution) {
    T mock = mock(clazz); // mock = Mock for ChildClass normally
    ...
}

// Calling like this, works as intended
withMockedConstruction(ChildClass.class, mockService -> { ... });
```

Is there any way to achieved this result by using only refied?
Can I force it somehow to check the refied type of a lambda function any way?
Is using the class the best solution in this scenario?

Comment: What language are you actually using?  What do you mean by reified?  You're using bits of Kotlin syntax, and I'm not certain what version of Mockito in Java actually has a function called `mock()` with no arguments, because [this Javadoc](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html) doesn't have such a method.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'm using Java. It's how Mockito's docs refer to the trick used to type infer ```mock()``` without specifing the class. Sorry if I confused the question somehow during my explanation, I'll make sure to clarify further if necessary. However, ever since version 4.9 of mockito-core it does have a ```mock()``` method with no arguments: [https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mock(T...)](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mock(T...))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "trick" being used to reify generics does not work transitively: you cannot *yourself* use generics and expect the trick to work.

```
public static <T extends ParentClass> void withMockedConstruction(
      Execution<T> execution) {
    T mock = mock();
```

At runtime, `T` is erased to `ParentClass`, and therefore `mock()` will reify `ParentClass`, not `T`.  (I suppose the implication is that this is a specific case where `@SafeVarargs` is actually wrong.)

You could *perhaps* identify the parameter type of the lambda, potentially with a custom functional interface with a default method adopting a trick like [this one](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.Class)), but at that point you're not saving much of anything compared to simply passing the `Class`, since you must always specify the lambda argument type using parentheses.